# Change Literal text on usercontrol VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, findcontrol

Good day

I have a VB.Net project. 
My main page is Display.aspx
I have various usercontrols (ascx) that use this page.
On one of these controls, I have a Literal, lblCatQuestion.
In the code behind of the control

```
 Protected WithEvents lblCatQuestion As Literal
```

What this literal basically does is it loads up with some text and radio buttons. When clicking on the radio buttons, a Jquery form pops up. Upon completing the form and saving and closing, this literal should now display a message.
The message comes from the main Display page's code behind

For purposes here, on the Display.aspx.vb

```
 Session("CatMessage") = "Completed"
    Dim label As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal
    label = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("lblCatQuestion"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal).Text = Session("CatMessage")
```

Problem is, when I debug, I always get a nullreferenceexception when trying to assign the text to the literal. 
When I look, the page here is described as

> display_aspx
>   [image]

but on my url, the page is

> Display.aspx?pid=4

Could this be cauing the nullreferenceexception? As the page is not exactly Display.aspx anymore, but Display.aspx?pid=4
[image]

How would I change the literal's text now?
How would I get the exact page, so that I can change the text value?

Thanks for the help

EDIT

This is declared in the control's code behind

```
 If Not Session("CatMessage") Is Nothing Then
            lblCatQuestion.Text = Session("CatMessage")
        End If
```

But the text does not change. Hence why I'm looking into a different method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Literal is within a user control, you have to look there, not within the page.

```
Session("CatMessage") = "Completed"
Dim label As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal
label = DirectCast(UserControl.FindControl("lblCatQuestion"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal).Text = Session("CatMessage")
```

Comment: i tried this. still didnt work. what i did have before was                                  If Not Session("CatMessage") Is Nothing Then
                lblCatQuestion.Text = Session("CatMessage")
            End If                               but that didnt refresh the label.  thats why i'm trying another way